# Topography / elevation data of Mars

Tags: mars, data-analysis, topographic-map

For a design project I'm looking for elevation data for Mars' surface - the idea is to replicate a surface area of Mars as a physical model, using the elevation data to create a very rough 3d model of that particular area's topography.

Where can I find such data?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Try this link http://geo.pds.nasa.gov/missions/mgs/megdr.html
This should have the data you're looking for, though you may need to process it a bit to get it into a format hat will be usable.

Comment: Thanks, any idea of where to get a "ready to use" bump-map or similar? Also, I'm also looking for other stellar objects like moons.

Comment: A google search will give colour coded maps of Mars topography, you need to know what scale you want to work on and look for something suitable. As for other bodies, find a the name of a probe that went there with a radar altimeter and search the Nasa website for it's data, or again google for maps. You can get most of the raw data from nasa (or esa) but depending on what you want to achieve a colour coded map may provide enough data.